# How to access inner dimensions of tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow

The output of my `conv2d` function is a 4-D tensor `[64, 32, 32, 64] = [batch_size, output_height, output_width, number of filters]`. I want to make 3 rows on both sides, and 3 columns also on both sides to zero of output matrix. So, that's why i want to create a similar tensor (mask_tensor) of size `[64, 26+3(zero_pad), 26+3 (zero_pad), 64]` and multiply with original matrix. I thought of accessing `[26, 26]` and put zero padding on it... 
How to access inner dimensions of tensor ?

```
import tensorflow as tf

drop_matrix = tf.constant(1, shape=[64, 26, 26, 64], dtype=tf.float32)
paddings = tf.constant([leave this dimension ,pick this dimension, pick this dimension, leave this dimension]  )
t = tf.pad(drop_matrix_one_full, paddings, "CONSTANT")
```

Comment: So basically you are asking how to access the middle values of an array in python?

Comment: yes exactly....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to access the inner dimensions but can pad per dimension by providing a list of the size of the padding per dimension of the tensor:

```
>>> drop_matrix = tf.constant(1, shape=[64, 26, 26, 64], dtype=tf.float32)
>>> drop_matrix
<tf.Tensor 'Const:0' shape=(64, 26, 26, 64) dtype=float32>
>>> x = tf.pad(drop_matrix, [[0,0], [3,3], [3,3], [0,0]])
>>> x
<tf.Tensor 'Pad:0' shape=(64, 32, 32, 64) dtype=float32>
```

You can set the value to pad with to something using constant_values parameter, but the default is 0 so that shouldn't be necessary. For clarification, the 2 elements in each list are padding on either side of that dimension, so padding on just one side could be done by [0,3] for that dimension.

Edited example to be fitting to the situation

Comment: but in your solution I guess i have a problem that at one time I can either pad all dimensions with zero or any other constant value. But I don't want to pad first and last dimension of my 4D-Tensor... i want to pad only inner dimension which is [26, 26 ] :(

Comment: So use [[0,0], [3,3], [3,3], [0,0]]. This padds the center 2 dimensions with 3 on each side, but pads the first and last dimensions with 0 on each side, so no padding. In my example, the first dimension isn't changed either.

Comment: What do you mean by this " but pads the first and last dimensions with 0 on each side, so no padding" ????

Comment: From Tensorflow documentation " For each dimension D of input, paddings[D, 0] indicates how many values to add before the contents of tensor in that dimension, and paddings[D, 1] indicates how many values to add after the contents of tensor in that dimension". I guess you mean this ???

Comment: Changed the example to be more fitting to your situation. Yes, I do mean that, but they use a rather complicated way to indicate indexing. With 0 on each side I mean 0 extra indexes are added, so no padding is done.

Comment: Thank you so much... But if there any way that first and last dimension should remain unchanged as I mentioned in my question above is my first dimension is batch_size and last dimension is number of filter_channels ...in my Conv2d function output... So I don't want disturb them you know :/

Comment: They will be unchanged. As you can see when comparing line 3 and line 6 of the example, these dimensions do not change size. They will also not change ordering in any way.

Comment: If the answer was helpful, please accept it so the question can be closed. Also, with reference to the rules on commenting, if you are grateful for the response upvote the answer instead of using a comment for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to remove the first and last value from the array :

```
import tensorflow as tf

drop_matrix = tf.constant(1, shape=[64, 26, 26, 64], dtype=tf.float32)
paddings = tf.constant([leave this dimension ,pick this dimension, pick this dimension, leave this dimension][1:-1]  )
t = tf.pad(drop_matrix_one_full, paddings, "CONSTANT")
```

By adding `[1:-1]` as accessors to your array, you will return an array without the first and last element, effectively accessing the *middle values*.

Comment: I tried this way t = tf.pad(drop_matrix_one_full[1: -1], paddings, "CONSTANT").... its not working :(